# How can I apply custom sort to this array of objects?

Tags: swift, realm

I have a collection of objects where I want to sort the object by SortDate where SortDate is sorted by date newest to current date then from future date to past date. E.g. If my Events array contains objects with SortDate equal to June 4, June 8 and June 20. I want to sort it so that June 8 is shown first then June 20 then June 4. Where June 8 is closest to today's date June 6. How can I do that?

Here's my attempt:

```
  self.eventsArray =  Array(self.realm.objects(Event.self).filter("EventType == \"Event\"").sorted(byKeyPath: "SortDate", ascending: false))
 let dateObjectsFiltered = self.eventsArray.filter ({ ($0.SortDate?.toDate)! > Date() })
  self.eventsArray = dateObjectsFiltered.sorted { return $0.SortDate! < $1.SortDate! }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with realm?

Comment: It's a realm object

Comment: If that is relevant to the problem, it should have been stated; if it isn't, it shouldn't have that tag.

Comment: It could be relevant though. I'm wondering if I should use a filtering and sort via realm or Swift for best case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this, assuming that all your date optionals are not nil.

```
func days(fromDate: Date, toDate: Date) -> Int {
    return Calendar.current.dateComponents(Set<Calendar.Component>([.day]), from: fromDate, to: toDate).day ?? 0
}

let today = Date()

self.eventsArray.sort {
    let first = days(fromDate: today, toDate: $0.SortDate!.toDate!)
    let second = days(fromDate: today, toDate: $1.SortDate!.toDate!)
    return (first >= 0 && second < 0) ? true : ((first < 0 && second >= 0) ? false : (first < second))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can custom sort the array using [Array's sort(by:) function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296801-sort).

Here is a sample:

```
import Foundation

struct event {
    var SortDate: Date
}

//Create the array
var unsortedArray = [event]()
unsortedArray.append(event(SortDate: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1528070400)))
unsortedArray.append(event(SortDate: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1528416000)))
unsortedArray.append(event(SortDate: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1529452800)))


//Determine the closest date to the current date
let currentDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
var lowestDiff = -1
var closestDate: Date?
var component:Set<Calendar.Component> = Set<Calendar.Component>()
component.insert(.second)

//Loop through the dates, keep track of the current closest date
for element in unsortedArray {
    let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents(component, from: currentDate, to: element.SortDate)

    if (lowestDiff == -1 || (abs(dateComponents.second!) < lowestDiff)) {
        lowestDiff = abs(dateComponents.second!)
        closestDate = element.SortDate
    }
}

//Sort the array
unsortedArray = unsortedArray.sorted(by:
    {
        //If the closest date is in the comparison, return the closest date as greater.
        if (closestDate != nil) {
            if ($0.SortDate == closestDate) {
                print($0.SortDate)
                return true
            }
            else if ($1.SortDate == closestDate){
                print($1.SortDate)
                return false
            }
        }

        //Otherwise, compare the dates normally
        return $0.SortDate > $1.SortDate
    }
)
```